# Preventing capitalization in OpenOffice Calc (or LibreOffice Calc)

Tags: openoffice, libreoffice, libreoffice-calc, openoffice-calc, text-formatting

In OpenOffice Calc (and LibreOffice Calc), the first letter of each cell is auto-corrected to be capitalized.

Is it possible to prevent this, without affecting the behavior of the other applications in the office suite?

Comment: I need this too. I need to enter a bunch of passwords and it's messing them all up! It's super annoying! I already turned off all the options under Tools > Autocorrect > Options!

Answer (score 1):

I am using LibreOffice Calc from r5.1.6.2

In the menu, under `Tools --> AutoCorrect Options --> Options` I found the setting ***Capitalize first letter of every sentence*** was selected.  De-selecting this option resulted in the behaviour you and I are looking for.

Before I applied the same fix as you, I had previously gone into `Tools --> Options --> Language Settings --> Writing Aids --> Options` and de-selected ***Check spelling as you type*** and ***Check uppercase words***, with no effect.  Otherwise I have no explanation for why my fix worked and yours did not.

Of course, this means that you and I will have to remember to capitalize the first letter of every sentence we type in Writer, but I had that habit drilled into me for so many years that I deeply doubt I will care.